# How to Extract the Word Following a Symbol?

Tags: c#, string

I have a string that could have any sentence in it but somewhere in that string will be the @ symbol, followed by an attached word, sort of like @username you see on some sites.

so maybe the string is "hey how are you" or it's "@john hey how are you".

IF there's an "@" in the string i want to pull what comes immediately after it into its own new string.

in this instance how can i pull "john" into a different string so i could theoretically notify this person of his new message? i'm trying to play with string.contains or .replace but i'm pretty new and having a hard time.

this btw is in c# asp.net

Comment: who should i award this to i'm new to the site and you all said kind of the same thing so i plan on teaching myself regular expressions on the web, but for now i don't know who i should award?

Comment: anyway, the question is well formed, clear and a good start for a beginner ;)

Comment: You should award the answer that suits you best ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should really learn regular expressions. This will work for you:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

var res = Regex.Match("hey @john how are you", @"@(\S+)");

if (res.Success)
{
    //john
    var name = res.Groups[1].Value;
}
```

Finds the first occurrence. If you want to find all you can use `Regex.Matches`. `\S` means anything else than a whitespace. This means it also make `hey @john, how are you` => `john,` and `@john123` => `john123` which may be wrong. Maybe `[a-zA-Z]` or similar would suit you better (depends on which characters the usernames is made of).  If you would give more examples, I could tune it :)

I can recommend this page:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/

and this tool where you can test your statements:

http://regexlib.com/RESilverlight.aspx

Comment: I would suggest this regex as an update `@([\w-]+)`, it will allow alphanumeric plus dashes and underscores to be part of the match.  Spaces, commas, colons, etc will not be part of the match.  You can also look at naming the group  `@(?<name>[\w-]+)` so that you can use `res.Groups[name].Value` instead of `[1]`

Comment: @Chad Partly agree :) I would make the reg. exp. to match EXACTLY what characters a username is permitted to consist of. Yup, but I wouldn't make the reg. exp. overly complicated to look at. An alternative is `res.Value.Substring(1)`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6.aspx) and [IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwb0bwyd.aspx) methods together to achieve this.

I hope this helps.

Thanks,
Damian

Comment: +1...A surprising number of answers here are recommending the unnecessary complexity of Regular Expressions, when these simple functions will do.

Comment: +1 for providing resources. Thus answering the full question.

Comment: @Robert Complexity of execution (performance), yes. But in my opinion `if (s.Contains("@") var name = s.SubString(s.IndexOf....` is less readable. Ex take a look on egrunin´s answer

Comment: @Chad, There are no what-if scenarios for beginners, just a "this is it". wax on, wax off ;)

Comment: @lasseespeholt But if any of your coworkers ever come across your regular expressions, they'll hate you, at least at most places I've worked...I've found that it's best to assume a macro-writing accountant will be the next person to sift through my code.

Comment: @Caspar Kleijne, I disagree, I think "beginners" should be taught the proper way the first time, not the *hackish* way

Comment: @smoore Why? If they know regular expressions and they are reasonable simple they should be fine :) but if they don't, then they have something to learn :D - seriously

Comment: @smoore, regexes are often simple.  And a tool like Expresso breaks it down no matter the complexity into something anybody can comprehend.

Comment: @lasseespeholt  That's true, and I wish my co-workers would look at things that way, but unfortunately they don't, many are still kicking and screaming about being drug into the "new" base languages (C#) my company has adopted :)

Comment: @Chad: `\w` already captures `_`, no need to specify it separately.

Comment: @Fredrik Mörk, indeed it does.

Comment: @Chad: he's new at this, why show him the chainsaw before the ripsaw?

Comment: anyone have a link to a sort of regular expressions for dummies article or resource site i can check out? i'd like to learn them

Comment: can anyone advise how i should award the right answer if you guys think it matters? you all kind of said just about the same thing i don't know who should get credit

Comment: @korben I have putted a few links in my answer :) And just accept the answer which helped you most. If you like, you can upvote the rest of the answers which helped you.

Comment: @egrunin, because if you're cutting down a tree, you use a chainsaw.  The right tool for the job...though, some would argue, depending on the total scope of what korben is attempting, the right tool might be a lexer/parser.

Answer (score 5):

Here's how you do it without regex:

```
string s = "hi there @john how are you";

string getTag(string s)
{
    int atSign = s.IndexOf("@");

    if (atSign == -1) return "";

    // start at @, stop at sentence or phrase end
    // I'm assuming this is English, of course
    // so we leave in ' and -
    int wordEnd = s.IndexOfAny(" .,;:!?", atSign); 

    if (wordEnd > -1)
        return s.Substring(atSign, wordEnd - atSign);
    else
        return s.Substring(atSign);

}
```

Comment: won't work. What about other punctuation marks, such as commas, exclamation marks, etc.

Comment: @Timothy: You can add all of those to the `IndexOfAny` call.

Comment: But not an apostrophe or comma, right? So this has to be explicit, even in a regex.

Comment: So, how about when there are more than 1 @? for example - "hi @matt, have you seen @john?"

Comment: @Ivan: he didn't say what behavior he wants there, so I left it out. I could adapt this to that case, but I'm @work :)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to solve this is using Regular Expressions.  You can find a great resource [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dotnet.html).

Using RegEx, you can search for the pattern you are after.  I always have to refer to some documentation to write one...

Here is a pattern to start with - "@(\w+)" - the @ will get matched, and then the parentheses will indicate that you want what comes after.  The "\w" means you want only word characters to match (a-z or A-Z), and the "+" indicates that there should be one or more word characters in a row.

Comment: The regex would work, but it is kind of an overkill and too advanced for a begginer. Thoughts?

Comment: I agree it is advanced, but using `Substring` and `IndexOf` are prone to exceptions and issues that won't be found without a lot of testing.

Comment: I don't think regexs are too advance. OP will have to learn them at some point... learning regular expressions has a bigger payoff It's string processing and pattern matching that regexes were made for (us programmers tend to forget that) and the question is a text processing problem.

Comment: @Damian: I disagree. Perhaps deciding which regex to use may be advanced, but the use of them is not advanced (at least, not in .NET)

Answer (score 1):

RegularExpressions. Dont know C#, but the RegEx  would be

`/(@[\w]+) /` - Everything in the parans is captured in a special variable, or attached to RegEx object.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Regex...

I think will be something like this

```
string userName = Regex.Match(yourString, "@(.+)\\s").Groups[1].Value;
```

Comment: It matches too much: `hey @john hey how are you` => `john hey how are`. `.` is everything besides line-breaks.

Comment: he's right i'm getting this problem, in the case of @john hey how are you i just want "john" not "john hey how" which is what i'm getting?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
var r = new Regex(@"@\w+");
foreach (Match m in r.Matches(stringToSearch))
    DoSomething(m.Value);
```

`DoSomething(string foundName)` is a function that handles name (found after @).
This will find all @names in `stringToSearch`